# how to retrieve Login Form password in Custom UserDetailsService

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Custom User class that extends the User(Spring Security's) class and Custome UserDetailsService class. This service queries the database using Hibernate service method to fetch user details. If there is no records found in the database for that userId, instead of throwing a UsernamNotFoundException,  I want to create a dummy Custom user object and pass the authentication with read-only attributes. But I can't get it working because, I am not sure how to retrieve the password value entered by user on the login page. I need to pass it to the custom user constructor to get it authenticated properly..

So, to sum it up, is there anyway to retrieve password entered by the user on login page inside the loadUserByUserName() method? Thanks in advance

Comment: I know that is not what you are asking, but what about to use roles for that? Make additional field in user table, for example role, and add your dummy user as other normal users to database, but set role ROLE_DUMMY_USER. In web-app you can check role of logged user and decide what he can do and what can't do according to the role he has.

Comment: thanks for the reply marioosh.. that was exactly my initial thought but the app allows single session per user. So can't have one record in the user table used by all dummy users..

Answer (score 2):

I am doing something in a similar vein a current project.  I have just started getting into Spring Security over the past 2 weeks, but I've really dug into it during that time (attached source, went through it in the debugger).

I have a Custom User class that extends *org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User* and a custom class that implements *org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService* interface.

As you know, the signature of the loadUserByUsername method in *UserDetailsService* interface specifies that a class implementing *UserDetails* interface is going to be returned.

Spring Security is going to take the class that implements *UserDetails* and check the username and password provided by login form / basic authentication / digest authentication / (whatever authentication scheme you selected) against the Username and Password in *UserDetails*.

I have not found a way that you can get at the credentials provided by the end user via authentication scheme.  If you want, I could try looking into it when I'm back at work tomorrow (I'm at home and writing this from memory.

Comment: thanks Philip for your kind offer for help. I hope you find some information on how to retrieve it.. I am doing the exact thing as your, extending the User class to have Customuser class and I ran into new issue with that.. If the principal is pre-authenticated by some third party app, I cannot seem to instantiate Custom User because there is no password..... :(

Answer (score 0):

I am running Spring 3.0.6 RELEASE and Spring Security 3.0.6 RELEASE.

I ran the code in my debugger.  You will not be able to get at the Authentication object from the custom *UserDetailsService*.

However, I believe you may be able to create your own AuthenticationProvider that gets at it: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-services.html

Please reference this code snippet from Spring Security's *org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager*, which loops over the AuthenticationProvider(s):

```
    for (AuthenticationProvider provider : getProviders()) {
        if (!provider.supports(toTest)) {
            continue;
        }

        logger.debug("Authentication attempt using " + provider.getClass().getName());

        try {
            result = provider.authenticate(authentication);

            if (result != null) {
                copyDetails(authentication, result);
                break;
            }
        } catch (AccountStatusException e) {
            // SEC-546: Avoid polling additional providers if auth failure is due to invalid account status
            eventPublisher.publishAuthenticationFailure(e, authentication);
            throw e;
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            lastException = e;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it loops over each AuthenticationProvider and passes in the Credentials.  Hope that helps!

Philip

Answer (score 0):

We are able to do something similar to what you're asking by extending AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.  There's an method retrieveUser(String _userName, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken _authToken) that you can override and put in your own custom logic.  The return object is a UserDetails.  So at this point you can create your own custom UserDetails and return it back to the framework (note:  you can set your read-only attributes in this method as well).

At this point Spring Security will not have tried to authenticate using the password.  They leave that to the additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails _userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken _authToken) method that you can also override.  Since this is where you would do your password validation it's ok to just skip the validation and let the method return.  At this point your anonymous user will be validated.

Finally add this into your security.xml

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="appUserSecurityService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

I hope this helps!